# Which is better ? JMeter script recorder or Blazemeter chrome plugin

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, blazemeter

I found many articles that script can be recorded with jmeter script recorder using firefox proxy.
But there are many article which says use Blazemeter chrome plugin.

Which is better and why?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a thing as "better" when it comes to recording network traffic, either a piece of software does its work or it doesn't.

Given both approaches produce valid [.jmx test plan](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) which exactly represents the network requests made by the browser via JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers - both approaches are good.

So it's a matter of convenience and in some cases security.

- On one hand BlazeMeter Chrome Extension is easier to use as you don't need to worry about proxies, [SSL certificates, HSTS, etc](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server/).
- On the other hand BlazeMeter Chrome extension sends recorded requests to BlazeMeter backend for converting it into JMeter and/or Selenium scripts so in some environments your IT security department may restrict the usage of this extension or it's quite popular to prohibit browser extensions installation at all

Comment: Thank you for the crisp reply... :-)